# $X\sim N(160,29.63)$, given : $P(X\leq 160)=\frac{1}{2}, P(X\leq 140)=\frac{1}{4}$,$P(X\geq 200)=?$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

$X\sim N(160,29.63)$, given : $P(X\leq 160)=\frac{1}{2}, P(X\leq 140)=\frac{1}{4}$

I want to find $P(X\geq 200)$.

Is it correct to say that $P(X\leq 160)=P(X\geq 160)=\frac{1}{2} \implies P(X\leq 320)=1 ?$

My try:

$P(X\geq200)=P(X\leq120)=P(\frac{X-160}{29.63}\leq\frac{120-160}{29.63})=P(\frac{X-160}{29.63}\leq-1.34)$

Here I get stuck.

I try to find $P(120\leq X \leq 140)$ since I know $P(X\leq 120)=P(X\leq 140)-P(120\leq X \leq 140)=\frac{1}{4}-P(120\leq X \leq 140)$

Help please ?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You are given the distribution explicitly, right?  So...why would you need those intermediate probabilities?

Comment: And why on earth would you imagine that $P(X≤160)=\frac 12=P(X≥160)\implies P(X≤320)=1$?

Comment: Usually in standard notation $N(\mu,\sigma^{2})\implies$ mean is $\mu$ and variance is $\sigma^{2}$. But the standard normal variate is $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$. So you should divide by $\sqrt{29.63}$ according to this notation. This is from wikipedia.

Comment: I got my problem; thank you